# exact-closed form solutions of recurrences

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

How can I find the exact-closed form solution of this recurrence?

$$f(n) = (1/2)f(n-2) + n/2,$$
where n is even, $f(0)=1$

My answer:

I try to guess a solution by unwinding the formula for f(n)

$f(n) = (1/2)f(n-2) + n/2$$

$= (1/2) ((1/2)f(n-4) + ((n-2)/2) )+n/2$

$=(1/2)^2f(n-4)+n/2^2+n/2 -2/2^2$

$=(1/2)^3f(n-6)+n/2^3+n/2^2+n/2 -2/2^2-4/2^3$

$=(1/2)^4f(n-8)+n/2^4+n/2^3+n/2^2+n/2 -2/2^2-4/2^3-6/2^4$

Continuing in this manner suggest the sum:

$f(n)=1/2^{(n/2)}f(0)+n(1/2^{n/2}+1/2^{(n/2)-1}+...+1/2)-(2/2^2+4/2^3+6/2^4+...)$

$f(n)=1/2^{(n/2)}+n(1-(1/2)^{n/2})-(2/2^2+4/2^3+6/2^4+...)$

How could I solve the expression $(2/2^2+4/2^3+6/2^4+...)$ and find the exact-closed form solution of this recurrence?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Look for a solution in the form $$f(n) = A r^n + B n + C$$

Comment: Sorry but I do not know how is this hint related to this question, could you please explain more about it?(There is only one way to solve this kind of recurrences in my lecture notes: unwind the formula and guess for a solution, so I do not know if there are other ways to solve it)

Answer (score 0):

Hint

Let $g(m)=f(m)+a_0+a_1m+\cdots$

$n=2f(n)-f(n-2)=2g(n)-g(n-2)+a_0(2-1)+a_1\{2n-(n-2)\}$

Set $a_i=0$ for $i\ge2$ and $a_1=1$ and $a_0+2a_1=0$

so that $g(n)=\dfrac{g(n-2)}2=\dfrac{g(n-2r)}{2^r}$

Set $2r=n$

Comment: I don’t understand why 2f(n)-2f(n-2)=2g(n)-g(n-2)+a(2-1)+a1(2n-(n-2)),where does the term a(2-1)+a1(2n-(n-2)) come from?How do you know that?

Answer (score 0):

Your direct question is about the sum
$$
\eqalign{
  & 2/2^{\,2}  + 4/2^{\,3}  + 6/2^{\,4}  +  \cdots  =   \cr 
  &  = 1 \cdot \left( {{1 \over 2}} \right)^{\,1}  + 2 \cdot \left( {{1 \over 2}} \right)^{\,2}  + 3 \cdot \left( {{1 \over 2}} \right)^{\,3}  +  \cdots  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,k} k \left( {{1 \over 2}} \right)^{\,k}  \cr} 
$$

Since
$$
\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,\left( {\,1\, \le } \right)\,k} {k\,z^{\,k} }  = z\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k} {k\,z^{\,k - 1} }
  = z{d \over {dz}}\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k} {z^{\,k} }  =   \cr 
  &  = z{d \over {dz}}{1 \over {\left( {1 - z} \right)}} = {z \over {\left( {1 - z} \right)^{\,2} }} \cr} 
$$
then the sum equals
$$
\sum\limits_{1\, \le \,k} k \left( {{1 \over 2}} \right)^{\,k}  = 2
$$

Comment: Sorry.Maybe I did not explain clearly about this question.The sequence 2/2^2 +4/2^2+... is a summation to n, not to infinity,and its first term 2/2^2 first appears when n=4, as you can see in my try to unwind the formula